# Will windows know if network path is local or not

Tags: windows, networking

Let's say I have a shared folder on my machine, for example : \MyMachine\foo.
If I try to access it on the "MyMachine" computer, will it be smart enough to know that it is on the same machine and won't try to use the network adapter and be super slow? I tested it by disabling my network adapter and it was still working, but it might have been because I disabled it that it checked locally instead of using the network adapter.

My concern for not wanting to use the network adapter is speed. Large amount of data needs to be acceded sometime by network path if used outside, but if it is getting acceded locally it has to be quickly.

Comment: If course.  If it is not local then it has a completely different pathname.  Like `\\server\share\dir\file.ext`.

Comment: Good thing i saw the link right when it was posted posted it because that exactly answer my question.

Comment: Yeah the app gives me error and does not allow to post it with details. Maybe because i tried to flag it as dup but i am pasting it below. Will try from desktop as the app might be wonky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every UNC is resolved down to it's core protocol address. Assuming a standard network of TCP/IP, your UNC will be resolved to local machine and the IP will be the same as your loopback IP. The network adapter won't be needed in this case so nothing will be sent over the network. In short, communication will be via the loopback address which does not require network.

Extracted from:

https://serverfault.com/questions/411389/does-traffic-from-accessing-locally-shared-file-via-unc-path-still-go-through-th

Answer (score 1):

It wont, because the changes are taking place in your computer.

However if someone else is trying to access that directory then your computer must send the directory's information to the other computer, thus using the network.

Comment: But my own machine will not use the network to access \\MyMachine\foo? So windows knows not to send it through the network. Kinda like router with local address and outside address, the router won't send the request to the ISP if it is local... So i was wondering if windows network path would be similar on a local network only. The router is an analogy.

Comment: Yes it will work that way, even if you are connecting to the localhost ip and sending data through the network connected to your own host, the computer wont consume network broadband.